# How do i get access to all front end pages on an opencart module?

Tags: opencart, opencart2.x, opencart-module, opencart2.3

Is there a way I can create an OpenCart module that has access to all the (front-end) pages of the store? 
What I want is for the user to not have to “bind” this module to all the layouts in order for it to exist in all pages. 
Basically I want to build a module that injects some js code to every page of the app and depending on some OpenCart hooks on the back-end to run some extra js code on front or some api requests on the back-end.
Thanks

Comment: Did you try to modify footer or header via vQmod or ocmod?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure exactly what you are looking for by saying you want a module to have "access" to all the (front-end) pages of the store. Modules have to be placed in layouts, and layouts can be assigned to multiple pages.

Each layout can have elements that are assigned specifically to areas you can designate (and customize). For example, you might want to create a special place for your module in the common header. You would simply create the controller, language and view files in a folder of your own designation (in my example, I will use the common folder), and let's call these files "loadjs".

Pattern these after the `common/header.php` and `.tpl` files. Just be sure to change the class and file names in the controller file to match. So you would create a `loadjs.php` file in the common directory of the controller folder that contains the `ControllerCommonLoadjs` class, a `loadjs.php` file in the `language/(your language)/common` folder, and a `loadjs.tpl` file in the `view/theme/(your theme name)/template/common` folder.

Add a `$data['loadjs'] = $this->load->controller('common/loadjs');` to your `controller/common/header.php` file and `<?php echo $loadjs; ?>` in your `view/theme/(your theme name)/template/common/header.tpl` file. You can now create your module.

However, to be able to add it to your layout you will need to make some changes to some admin files. `Add $_['text_loadjs'] = 'Loadjs';` to your `admin/language/(your language)/design/layout.php` file and `$data['text_loadjs'] = $this->language->get('text_loadjs');` to your `admin/controller/design/layout.php` file.

You will need to make a change to your `admin/view/template/design/layout_form.tpl` file as well. Look for the following code:

```
<option value="content_top" selected="selected"><?php echo $text_content_top; ?></option>
<?php } else { ?>
<option value="content_top"><?php echo $text_content_top; ?></option>
<?php } ?>
<?php if ($layout_module['position'] == 'content_bottom') { ?>
<option value="content_bottom" selected="selected"><?php echo $text_content_bottom; ?></option>
<?php } else { ?>
<option value="content_bottom"><?php echo $text_content_bottom; ?></option>
<?php } ?>
```

and add the following code just below that:

```
<?php if ($layout_module['position'] == 'loadjs') { ?>
<option value="loadjs" selected="selected"><?php echo $text_loadjs; ?></option>
<?php } else { ?>
<option value="loadjs"><?php echo $text_loadjs; ?></option>
<?php } ?>
```

Now, login to your OpenCart Dashboard and add your module to the loadjs position on your layout. And that should do it.

Comment: thanks you so much for your comment. What i want is to add a javascript to the header regardless of theme and without having the user edit any files. Is that possible?

Comment: Ok, well, you don't need to add a module for that. I am assuming from your original request to have access to "all" front-end pages of the site, you want to put the same javascript on each page. If that is all you want, and all your pages share the same view/theme/(your theme name or default)/template/common/header.tpl file, then all you need to do is add the javascript directly into the header (at least this is the most simplest and direct way.) There are other ways, but they get progressively more involved.

Comment: If you are using the default header.tpl file you will only need to add the javascript one time regardless of what theme you choose. If you use customized header.tpl files in each of your themes, you will need to add the javascript to each theme header.tpl file.

Comment: I am developing a module utilizing opencart events/hooks such as checkout/login etc to build a referral scheme. So i was aiming for a more hand-off installation experience for the users of the module. But from what i understand we cannot avoid the step where users need to add the javascript to the header.tpl file of their theme. Am i right?

Comment: I'm sorry, maybe I am misunderstanding your question. Are you developing some sort of a theme that you are either selling to or giving away to others? Why would the user have to modify the .tpl file, or any of the OpenCart program files anyway?

Comment: I am developing a plugin/module that utilizes events to formulate a referral program. The whole thing is also connected with a javascript popup (thus needing a javascript at head). In a nutshell users buy something and refer their friends. If one of them friends logs in into the store then a popup appears in the right lower section telling them that they have a discount coupon. Is that clearer? Again really appreciate that you are taking time for this.

Comment: Thanks for the added explanation and the time you took for it. Let me see if I am understanding you correctly: You need to set up a plugin/module so that when one of your users refers a friend (I presume this will be done through a module in one of their account pages) and that friend registers with your store, a popup will appear when they log in telling them they have a discount coupon. What event will cause the coupon to disappear?